# Update a specific XML Element without caring what value is there

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, xelement

Although there are a lot of examples on how to do this, I seem to be stuck and I cannot find anything out there to help me. I want to update the value of the index without testing it's previous value. I know this must be easy but I'm stumped.

I initially create my xml document

```
XDocument master;
master = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("ERoot",
    new XElement("EHeader"),
    new XElement("EData")));
master.Save(MasterXml);
```

and later add the index node

```
myIndex = 0;
XElement treename = XElement.Load(MasterXml);
XElement head = treename.Element("EHeader");

head.Add(new XElement("Index", myIndex));
treename.Save(MasterXml);
```

and the XML file looks ok

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ERoot> 
    <EHeader> 
        <Index>0</Index> 
    </EHeader> 
    <EData/> 
</ERoot>
```

So, how do I update the Index value without caring what value was there before. All the examples I see are selecting the ... something.Value == "0" ... and I may not know what it is. I just want to overwrite and value that may be there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
master.Element("ERoot").Element("EHeader").Element("Index").SetValue(3);
```

or

```
master.Descendants("Index").First().SetValue(3);
```

P.S. You cant't get element `EHeader` by

```
treename.Element("EHeader");
```

must be

```
treename.Element("ERoot").Element("EHeader");
```

Comment: Thanks Hamlet. Your first answer gave me a null exception although everything looked fine. I'm still trying to understand why that did not work. But your suggestion using Descendants worked! I'm going to do more testing later today. Thanks again